# How to read and write UTF-8 strings in excel using Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am using a Groovy Script for automating a WEB Service test case in SOAPUI.
The groovy script will read an Excel sheet containing UTF-8 strings and send that as an input in the Web Service.

However the problem is that in Groovy I am not able to read the UTF-8 strings.
Can someone please suggest any solution?

I have tried to do the following:

```
Workbook workbook1 = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("testdata.xls").getText("UTF-8")) 
Sheet sheet1 = workbook1.getSheet(0)
numberOfRows = sheet1.getRows().toInteger()
testStep = myTestCase.getTestStepByName("Property -Looper")
testStep.setPropertyValue("Total", numberOfRows.toString())
counter = testStep.getPropertyValue("Count").toString()
counter = counter.toInteger()

next = (counter > numberOfRows-1?0: counter+1)

Cell qualifiedUser = sheet1.getCell(0,counter)
```

The testdata.xls file will be something like:
[image]

Comment: I believe, the numbers added in the file are not in English and they seemed to be showing correct.

Comment: @Rao The Strings appear as Nepali in Excel Sheet. But when we click on the cell they are converted to English. Same is happening when I am trying to load the values in the Script. Excel is giving English Values for the corresponding UTF-8(Nepali in my case) numbers.